# Local Position of Bone wrt Model

Tags: c#, xna

I have a requirement to get either position matrix or position vector of a bone (say wheel) with respect to my model (car).

What I have tried -

```
Vector3.Transform(mesh.BoundingSphere.Center , transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]*Matrix.CreateScale(o.Scaling )))
```

Above doesn't give accurate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to calculate the absolute transforms for each bone. The [CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.model.copyabsolutebonetransformsto) method can do it for you.

It is equivalent to the following code:

```
    /// <summary>Calculates the absolute bone transformation matrices in model space</summary>
    private void calculateAbsoluteBoneTransforms() {

      // Obtain the local transform for the bind pose of all bones
      this.model.CopyBoneTransformsTo(this.absoluteBoneTransforms);

      // Convert the relative bone transforms into absolute transforms
      ModelBoneCollection bones = this.model.Bones;
      for (int index = 0; index < bones.Count; ++index) {

        // Take over the bone transform and apply its user-specified transformation
        this.absoluteBoneTransforms[index] =
          this.boneTransforms[index] * bones[index].Transform;

        // Calculate the absolute transform of the bone in model space.
        // Content processors sort bones so that parent bones always appear
        // before their children, thus this works like a matrix stack,
        // resolving the full bone hierarchy in minimal steps.
        ModelBone bone = bones[index];
        if (bone.Parent != null) {
          int parentIndex = bone.Parent.Index;
          this.absoluteBoneTransforms[index] *= this.absoluteBoneTransforms[parentIndex];
        }
      }

    }
```

Taken from [here](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/graphics/mesh-based-bone-animation/).

Comment: Excellent thanx ;)
I had tried something like -
model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);
wheelShape[i].LocalPose = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]*Matrix.CreateScale(WheelScale)
was initially correct but as car rotated, wheels deformed
The solution worked great